# Why a simple program does not start right away

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, flush

Please understand that I can not ask specifically because I don't know the keywords related this problem.

The problem is that if run the program in the following source, the program will not run immediately.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int main() {
  bool stop = false;
  pcap_t *pcp = nullptr;
  pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr = nullptr;
  const u_char *packet = nullptr;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  int res = 0;

  //It works normally. "here" printed.
  std::cout << "here"
  //----------- I think pcap_open_live() block the program --------------
  pcp = pcap_open_live("enp0s3", BUFSIZ, 0, -1, errbuf);
  //if run following, the program print "captured!" phrase.
  //std::cout << "any string\n";
  if (pcp == nullptr) {
    return 0;
  }
  //if run following, the program print "captured!" phrase.
  //std::cout << "any string\n";
  while (!stop) {
    while (res == 0) {
      res = pcap_next_ex(pcp, &pkthdr, &packet);
    }
    if (res < 0) {
      stop = true;
    } else {
      std::cout << "captured!\n";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The program is executed under the following two conditions.

- enter any key
- print stdout like a comment

Why is this happening, and how does the program work immediately?

Comment: can't you debug it to find out where it is blocking?

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine whether the program is executed or not?  (i.e. is there some particular output on stdout that you look to see, or some network behavior, or ???)

Comment: `@JeremyFriesner` "captured!\n" I want the phrase to be printed

Comment: @Sanjeev
I think `pcap_next_ex(pcp, &pkthdr, &packet)` function is blocking at first time..

Comment: @김현우 there will be timeout value defined in the pcap_open call, you have to look on that. also put print("captured") statement in the else block. if pcap_next_ex is returning 0 then its timeout, you should not print captured in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you set a negative value for ***to_ms***, that is the buffer timeout, in your call to

`pcap_open_live(const char *device, int snaplen, int promisc, int to_ms, char *errbuf)`

As it is stated in [here](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_live.3pcap.html), the 4th parameter in pcap_open_live()

> specifies the packet buffer timeout, as a non-negative value, in
>   milliseconds

If you read the main [pcap page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html), it states that

> *packet buffer timeout*:
>
> If, when capturing, packets are delivered as
>   soon as they arrive, the application capturing the packets will be
>   woken up for each packet as it arrives, and might have to make one or
>   more calls to the operating system to fetch each packet. If, instead,
>   packets are not delivered as soon as they arrive, but are delivered
>   after a short delay (called a "packet buffer timeout"), more than one
>   packet can be accumulated before the packets are delivered, so that a
>   single wakeup would be done for multiple packets, and each set of
>   calls made to the operating system would supply multiple packets,
>   rather than a single packet. This reduces the per-packet CPU overhead
>   if packets are arriving at a high rate, increasing the number of
>   packets per second that can be captured. The packet buffer timeout is
>   required so that an application won't wait for the operating system's
>   capture buffer to fill up before packets are delivered; if packets are
>   arriving slowly, that wait could take an arbitrarily long period of
>   time.

At the end of this paragraph it states that:

> A negative value is invalid; the result of setting the timeout to a
>   negative value is unpredictable.

So I suggest you to try to set that to 0 or positive values to see if the behaviour is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If run the program using ssh in the Nat environment, the "captured!" output occurs the actual packet transmitted. The problem is not blocking but no actual transport packet. thank you for your attention.